# How to solve $23^{{2020}^{2020}} \bmod 37$? Please see the body of the question.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

How to solve $$23^{{2020}^{2020}} \mod 37.$$  Below given is my understanding of trying to solve the problem.

From $$x^{p-1} = 1 \mod p$$
I deduce that $$23^{2020} \mod 37$$ would be $$23^{56.36+4} \mod 37$$ which is further simplified as $$23^{4} \mod 37$$ as $$23^{\alpha .36} = 1 \mod 37$$

Keeping the above in mind, I am wondering if there is anyway of solving $$23^{{2020}^{2020}} \mod 37.$$  I'm clueless about how to simplify the double exponent.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Since $37$ is prime, you should reduce the exponent $(2020^{2020})$ modulo $36$

Comment: Hi @J.W.Tanner, Thank for the comment. Based on what you just said, is the following right? $$2020^{2020} \mod 36$$ = $$2020^{56 * 36+4} \mod 36$$ = $$2020^{56} * 2020^{4} \mod 36$$  as $$2020^{36} = 1 \mod 36$$

Comment: No; for one thing, $2020^{36}$ is even; Euler's theorem applies when the base and modulus are relatively prime

Comment: For the quickest way see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2061396/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3161162/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3105802/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you so much! That helps break down the concepts! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain in more detail what [Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1827/ross-millikan) suggested,

note that $2020^{2020}\equiv0\pmod4$ and $2020^{2020}\equiv 4^{336\times6+4}\equiv4^4\equiv4\pmod9$

($4^6\equiv1\pmod9$ by [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)),

so $2020^{2020}\equiv4\pmod{36}$ by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

From $x^{36} \equiv 1 \pmod {37}$ what you care about is the exponent $\bmod 36$.  Now you need to evaluate (not solve) $2020^{2020} \pmod {36}$.  The factors of $2$ are easy, as you quickly have two of them. Then you are only interested in evaluating it $\bmod 9$.  Back to you.

Comment: Thank you! that explains!